# I need help to find the correct output (convert word to lower case)

Tags: python

Here is my my program:

```
def word_frequencies(words):
    l=[]
    l=words.split()
    wordfreq=[l.count(p) for p in l]
    return(dict(zip(l,wordfreq)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = input("Enter a sentence: ")
    your_dictionary = word_frequencies(words)
    sorted_keys = sorted(your_dictionary.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
        print(key + ': ' + str(your_dictionary[key]))
```

Here is my output:

Enter a sentence: ZyBooks now zyBooks later zyBooks forever

ZyBooks: 1
forever: 1
later: 1
now: 1
zyBooks: 2

Here is my expectation:

Enter a sentence: ZyBooks now zyBooks later zyBooks forever

forever: 1
later: 1
now: 1
zybooks: 3

Comment: So you want your count to be case-insensitive, where it currently is case-sensitive? Something like `l = list(map(lambda s: s.lower(), l))` (also, don't name lists `l`, it's hard to tell these apart: `l|I`, depending on the font

Comment: `ZyBooks` is not the same as `zyBooks`.  Your code doesn't convert the words to lowercase.  Why are you expecting it to?

Comment: The words are case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower) function to make all words lowercase before counting them.

For example:

```py
def word_frequencies(words):
    l = words.lower().split()
    # ...
```

Comment: Still not correct, Here is what I have:                                                                                       ZyBooks: 0
forever: 1
later: 1
now: 1
zyBooks: 0

Comment: @user20577449 It should be fixed now, calling `lower` in the loop caused a bug

Answer (score 0):

```
def word_frequencies(words):
    return {p: words.count(p) for p in set(words)}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = input("Enter a sentence: ").lower().split()
    print(*sorted(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in word_frequencies(words).items()))
```

Transform the input to lowercase using `lower()` method and split it before calling the function, so your function is only responsible for one task. Print the sorted result by unpacking the return value from the function.

Output:

```
Enter a sentence: ZyBooks now zyBooks later zyBooks forever
forever: 1 later: 1 now: 1 zybooks: 3
```